# How to add Android-wheel library to android studio?

Tags: android, github, android-studio, build.gradle, importerror

How to add Android-wheel library(https://github.com/chemalarrea/Android-wheel) to android studio?

Comment: first try then let us know what kind of issues you have.

Comment: like any other library. Nothing different.

Comment: @EluciusFTW Hello, This library is made four years ago.That time android studio was not created. and I don't know how to add it to android studio.

Comment: @praveenSharma This library is made four years ago.That time android studio was not created. and I don't know how to add it to android studio.basically.

Comment: @mohoranjbar check out my answer. It may help you.

Comment: have you ever migrate eclipse project to android studio? notice that all the library project is behave as module. and inside setting.gradle it define as include ':library'

Answer (score 3):

Its as simple as other library integration in android studio.
I've listed steps below just follow it you will get android-wheel lib support to your studio project.

1) Download library from github.
2) go to android studio project File -> new -> import module.
   - choose android-wheel library.

after above steps library should appear within android studio project explorer.

now you have to add dependency for that follow below steps

1) Right click on your project -> choose Open module settings -> from left
   panel choose your project (not android-wheel library)
2) after choosing your project go to dependencies tab in right side frame.
3) press '+' and choose module dependencies and select android-wheel lib.

That's it...

Happy Coding! :)

Comment: If any issue do post your query. I will try to resolve it. If it resolves your problem please mark this as **Answer**

Comment: Warning:Dependency xxxxxxx:wheel:unspecified on project app resolves to an APK archive which is not supported as a compilation dependency. File: C:\Users\xxxxxxx\AndroidStudioProjects\xxxxxx\wheel\build\outputs\apk\wheel-release-unsigned.apk

Comment: strange! Let me do it by self and will let you know.

Comment: Hello Shrenik.I copid the Library Src folder manually and my problem was solved.Thanks.

Comment: Cheers! If my answer helped you or is correct way please hit the green tick to mark it as answer.

Answer (score -1):

Please find how to import any module to android studio project from here :

Please follow below steps :

1. Click on File -> New -> Import New Module.
2. Add Souce Directory path as library root level path.
3. Click 'OK' and 'Finish'.
4. Go to project setting -> Modules -> app -> dependencies -> click in '+' ->
   add module ->add wheel module here.

Now build your project and run.And if you found any error let me know.

Please refer below link for reference.!!

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32118213/4018207

Thanks

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Rob : Thanks for suggestion..!!